# Can't reach Django web dev server from Host OS using VirtualBox

Tags: python, django, virtualbox

I'm having trouble trying to reach my Django web dev server inside VirtualBox (4.2.8). What I'm trying to do is connect through the web browser in my Host OS to the web dev server running in the Guest OS, but I'm getting an error:

```
504 Gateway Timeout
Gateway timeout expired while waiting for server response
```

Here is some information about my system:

## Host OS

- Windows XP SP3 32bits
- IP: 10.8.8.205
- Gateway: 10.8.8.254

## Guest OS

- Ubuntu 13.04 32bits
- IP: 10.8.8.220
- Django 1.5
- Python 2.7

## Additional Info

- I'm using virtualenv
- The command used to run the webserver is `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
- The Network Adapter in VirtualBox is set to "bridge"
- Inside the Guest OS I can reach my site using `http://127.0.0.1:8000` but I **can't** reach it using `http://localhost:8000` or `http://10.8.8.220:8000`
- In my Host OS I **can't** reach the web dev server using `http://10.8.8.220:8000`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

### UPDATE

Inside my VM, if I set Firefox to not use the proxy settings for the IP 10.8.8.220 then I can reach the webserver using that IP in the web browser no matter if I start the server using the VM IP or 0.0.0.0:8000. But still can't reach it from the Host OS even if I configure Firefox the same way

Comment: Can you reach it from inside the vm? If you only have a text prompt, try `wget`ing the site.

Comment: Try `manage.py runserver 10.8.8.220:8000`

Comment: @JoeFrambach I have updated my question

Comment: Can you ping the guest OS from host with 10.8.8.220

Comment: @dusual the Guest OS is responding the ping from the Host OS

Comment: what happens when you `curl`/`wget` from outside the VM? the issue could be with your browser

Answer (score -1):

For whatever reason, setting a proxy exception in Firefox in the Host OS, is not working as expected but in Chrome is

Comment: This should be an update or comment to your question, not an answer.